# difference between t:type="grid" and t:grid in tapestry

Tags: tapestry

in tapestry we can use the component in two ways

```
<t:type="grid" t:source="persons" t:row="person" t:encoder="personEncoder" t:include="id,firstname,lastname,startdate" t:add="delete"\>
```

or we can use

```
<t:grid source="persons" row="person" encoder="personEncoder" include="id,firstname,lastname,startdate" add="delete"></t:grid>
```

So my question is that is there any difference or specific reason to use the components in two different way?

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the first one really work? I think you mean

```
<table t:type="grid" ... />
```

vs.

```
<t:grid ... />
```

If so, there is no functional difference. I always prefer using the first style because it looks like proper HTML with instrumentation instructions for Tapestry, rather than just a bunch of Tapestry-specific tags.

The `t:` prefix for component parameters refers to the Tapestry namespace and is the clean way to define value bindings. Both styles will work with either `t:` present or omitted, as it is optional in most places, except in the odd case when it is not. (For example, you'll sometimes want both `id` and `t:id` on `Zone` components, and they'll actually mean different things.)

**TL;DR:** Use the `<table t:type="grid" t:source="" ... />` style.

Comment: Hi, yes the first one works because i am using it. thanks for your answer. one more question, do you have any idea about the tapestry editor where we can get the auto-suggestion kind of facility?

Answer (score 0):

Both versions should be correct, first one is used when you have some designer make template for site. So that he does not have to bother with tapestry.